# Exception when accessing shadow root DOM on webpage with Selenium and Chrome Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom

I'm trying to access the shadow root DOM on a web page using Java with Selenium and Chrome Webdriver. Up until today, I've been doing this successfully using the following line

```
WebElement ele = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element);
```

However, after Google Chrome updated itself today, I was forced to update Chrome Webdriver, and now I get the following exception:

Error: class com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.WebElement (com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap and org.openqa.selenium.WebElement are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

My configuration is
Google Chrome  96.0.4664.45,
Selenium 4.0,
Eclipse 4.21.0/JDK jdk-15.0.2

I can avoid an exception by doing this:

```
List <WebElement> eleList = (List <WebElement>) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
                .executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot.children", element);
                    return eleList.get(0);
```

but it doesn't open up the shadow root element for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own solution in case it helps someone:

1. download automation-0.1.3.jar from maven and add to project. see
   https://github.com/sukgu/shadow-automation-selenium/wiki
2. new code:

   ```
             Shadow shadow = new Shadow(driver);

             WebElement myWebElement=shadow.findElement("div.content");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "children" use "childNodes".

Examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/shadowRoot#examples

```
List <WebElement> eleList = (List <WebElement>) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
            .executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot.childNodes", element);
                return eleList.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast to `WebElement` any longer, it needs to be `SearchContext` (this works for all versions of Chrome, not just Chrome 96).

Read all the details here: https://titusfortner.com/2021/11/22/shadow-dom-selenium.html